# How to merge two containers (vectors/lists) of different structs, but with one common parameter in C++

Tags: c++, merge, containers

Using C++ with boost/stl, how can I merge two lists of different objects, say, A and B? They have some common and some different fields/properties and do not share unique id.

```
class A
{
   int id;
   double smth;
}

class B
{
   int id;
   std::string name;
   Type type;
}

class C
{
   int id;
   std::string name;
   Type type;
   double smth;
}
```

So idea is that I have e.g. `std::list<A>` and `std::list<B>` and I want to easily merge them to `std::list<C>`

Comment: How do you construct `C` from `A`, is `id` an identifier so if `a.id == b.id`, `C` has to be construct from `a` and `b` ?

Comment: @Jarod42, I think `a.id != b.id` always. I'm basing this on "... do not share unique id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to obtain a JOIN (--as it's called in SQL). Do the following:

- Sort both lists by id.
- Loop over both and merge them -- the actual procedure here differs whether you want an INNER, LEFT, RIGHT or FULL OUTER JOIN. I suppose you want an INNER JOIN, that is: include a variable in `std::list<C>` only if both `id`'s exist.

Here is a small code to accomplish that:

```
auto compare =  [](auto const& u, auto const& v) { return u.id < v.id;};

std::list<A> a;
a.sort(compare);
std::list<B> b;
b.sort(compare);

std::list<C> c;
auto ita = std::begin(a);
auto itb = std::begin(b);
while(ita != std::end(a) && itb != std::end(b))
{
    if(ita->id == itb->id)
    {
        c.emplace_back(*ita, *itb);
        ++ita;
        ++itb;
    }
    else if(ita->id < itb->id)
    {
        ++ita;
    }
    else
    {
        ++itb;
    }         
}
```

In order to work you also need a constructor in `C` which merges `A` and `B`:

```
C(A const& a, B const& b) : /* assign the stuff */ {}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8df9e6a64066c11a). It compiles and should work but it's untested.

Answer (score 1):

Provide an adaptor/converter and use it.

```
struct Type{};

struct A
{
    int id;
    double smth;
};

struct B
{
    int id;
    std::string name;
    Type type;
};

struct C
{
    int id;
    std::string name;
    Type type;
    double smth;

    C(const B& b) : id(b.id), name(b.name), type(b.type){}
    C(const A& a) : id(a.id), smth(a.smth) {}
};

int main() {

    std::vector<A> a = {{5, 0.6f}, {3, 0.3f}};
    std::vector<C> c;
    c.insert(c.end(), a.cbegin(), a.cend());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to initialize the unused members as well. At least the ones w/o default initialization (e.g. `smth` when converting from B) .

Answer (score 0):

You can use transform with a simple functor:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/013d0073bbfd253a)</kbd>**

```
enum Type { T1,T2,T3,TA };

struct A
{
   int id;
   double smth;
};

struct B
{
   int id;
   std::string name;
   Type type;
};

struct C
{
   int id;
   std::string name;
   Type type;
   double smth;
};

struct MakeC {
    C operator()(A const& a) const { return { a.id, "",     TA,     a.smth }; }
    C operator()(B const& b) const { return { b.id, b.name, b.type, 0.0    }; }
};

#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<A> as(10);
    std::vector<B> bs(10);

    std::vector<C> cs;

    std::transform(as.begin(), as.end(), back_inserter(cs), MakeC());
    std::transform(bs.begin(), bs.end(), back_inserter(cs), MakeC());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for anyone looking, here is my solution:

```
   std::transform
   (
      A_vect.begin(), A_vect.end(), 
      std::back_inserter(B_vect), 
      [](const A &a) -> B
      {
         B b;
         b.id   = a.id;
         
         return b;
      }
   );
```

However this does not produce a sorted container in the end.